# Get Empty Column Back

Tags: sql, mdx

In TSQL I can do

```
Select Column1, Column2, '' as Column3, 0 as Column4
From MyTable
```

I am trying my MDX as:

```
SELECT
{Measures.Measure1} ON COLUMNS
{
    Dimension1.DimensionColumn1.DimensionColumn1.Members,
    '',
    0
} ON ROWS
FROM  [CubeName]
```

This does not work - I get the following error message

```
Executing the query ...
Query (12, 1) Parser: The syntax for '{' is incorrect.
```

Question: How do I return empty or Zero `ON ROWS` in MDX?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the constant as an expression:

```
WITH
MEMBER MEASURES.CONSTANTVALUE AS 1
SELECT {MEASURES.CONSTANTVALUE} ON COLUMNS
FROM [cube]
```